# Change certain resource strings with robolectric

Tags: robolectric

I have a working robolectric and want to test a component of my application that does HTTP request. Since I don't want these requests to go to my live server but instead to a local test server I want to override a string resources (that contains the servers hostname) during testing.

However, I'm not capable of finding anything in the robolectric documentation that goes remotely in the direction I want :(

Comment: Its hard to say without seeing how you are currently wiring your requests with the current string.

Answer (score 7):

I've faced a similar issue in Robolectric 3; you can override a resource at application level using Mockito partial mocks.

First, you tell Robolectric to used a partially mocked Application and to return that when the application context is used: (thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31386831/327648)

```
RuntimeEnvironment.application = spy(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
when(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext())
    .thenReturn(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
```

Then you partially mock the Resources object:

```
Resources spiedResources = spy(app.getResources());
when(app.getResources())
    .thenReturn(spiedResources);
```

Then you can do the real override:

```
when(spiedResources.getString(R.string.server_address))
    .thenReturn("local server address");
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the technique mentioned at http://robolectric.blogspot.com/2013/04/the-test-lifecycle-in-20.html

This will allow you to override [`getResources()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getResources%28%29) and use spying to return a hardcoded String or (by default) the String loaded from res/values:

```
@Override
public Resources getResources() {
    Resources resources = spy(super.getResources());
    when(resources.getString(R.string.server_address)).thenReturn("local test server address");

    return resources;
}
```