# Shadowing getFilesDir() in Robolectric 3

Tags: android, robolectric

I'd like to shadow `Context.getFilesDir()` in order to "virtualize" the filesystem  my app is running in the test environment, but I can't find the right enclosing class to shadow.

I tried shadowing `Context`:

```
@Implements(Context.class)
public class MyShadow extends ShadowContext {
    private File testRoot;

    public MyShadow() {
        testRoot = new File(FileUtils.getTempDirectory(), "androidTestRoot-" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @Implementation
    public File getFilesDir() {
        return new File(testRoot, "data/data/com.myapp/files");
    }
}
```

but the method is never called, because apparently my app calls `ContextWrapper.getFilesDir()` which is not shadowed.

`ContextWrapper` is shadowed by Robolectric's `ShadowContextWrapper`. But even if I shadow `ContextWrapper` changing my class header as

```
@Implements(ContextWrapper.class)
public class MyShadow extends ShadowContextWrapper
```

my method isn't called too.

`ShadowContext`, the superclass of `ShadowContextWrapper`, is the shadow of `Context`, but I cannot find the concrete implementation of `getFilesDir()` that is called.

So my question is: is it possible to shadow `getFilesDir()` ? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure of what you're trying to do, but I have used the following to get the data directory on Robolectric tests:

```
RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
```

From that I have been able to create dummy files for whatever purpose I need in a test. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that class. Seems like Robolectric creates a directory like `/tmp/<random string>/files`. My intention is to change that directory so it points to something like `/tmp/<random string>/data/data/com.myapp/files`. I tried replacing the application with a partial mock so that `getFilesDir()` returns the desired path, but nothing seemed to change...

Comment: You might need to partial mock the `getApplicationContext()` method, and point it to a partial mock of the original context, in order to get it to point where you need to. This might sound a little bit cumbersome though, so other option would be to use some Dependency Injection to re-implement the context method.

Comment: It worked! I've made RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext() point to RuntimeEnvironment.appilcation itself: `File filesDir = new File(testRoot, "data/data/" + RuntimeEnvironment.application.getPackageName() + "/files");
RuntimeEnvironment.application = spy(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
when(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext()).thenReturn(RuntimeEnvironment.application);when(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getFilesDir()).thenReturn(filesDir);`

Comment: RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();        Does this return the actual android file system ? I was just passing  RuntimeEnvironment.application. to an instance of a class that uses context to manipulate files